# The word 'lavra'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, terminology

Where can I find a dictionary which contains an article on the word *lavra*? What does the word mean and is it really used?

Comment: Where did you see it or hear it?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavra). I have never encountered the word, probably because it seems to be used only in discussion of early Oriental and Orthodox Christian eremitical communities.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey in a chart with irregular endings in the plural forms.

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/lavra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an English word, except as a borrowing from Greek. It means a particular sort of religious community, primarily in the Orthodox Christian church(es). It's not used except by people who are talking about religious communities, because it's not a common phenomenon in English-speaking countries.

You'll find it in an encyclopedia, or a dictionary of religion, not a general dictionary.